# Динамическая генерация форм Angular

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

В зависимости от полученных данных необходимо динамически вывести несколько форм.
Каждая форма предусматривает динамическое добавление дополнительных инпутов.
Последняя задача решена, но сейчас доп. инпуты добавляются сразу ко всем формам.
Не понятно как на OnInit сгенерировать несколько уникальных форм.

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of selectedFilters">
      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
        <div>{{item}}</div>
        <div formArrayName="items"
        *ngFor="let item of form.controls['items'].controls; let i = index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <input formControlName='name'>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="addNext()">Add field</button>
      </form>
    </div>

 //==============

 form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([this.createItem()])
    });
  }

  createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: '',
    });
  }

  addNext() {
    (this.form.controls['items'] as FormArray).push(this.createItem());
  }
```

Comment: это довольно таки сложная задача, я б на вашем месте подумал в первую очередь о декомпозиции, сделать компоненты которые байндингами будут принимать `selectedFilter` и внутри у каждого компонента будет своя форма, задача упрощается

Comment: Я хотел все сделать в рамках одной формы, но все равно т.к. [formGroupName]="i" новые поля добавляются сразу ко всем.
А чем в моем случае декомпозиция поможет?

Comment: А, понял, спасибо большое!

Comment: декомпозиция - 1. производительность 2. не будет танцев с бубном с одной формой 3. вы точно сможете контролировать поведение форм, так как они будут изолированы в компонентах, что позволяет сразу избежать побочных эффектов, также вам не придется работать с кучами индексов

Comment: Просто я не уверен, правильно ли все бить на разные формы. Может это правильно все в одной форме делать.

Comment: правильно, не сомневайтесь, на больших проектах когда выскакивают подобного рода задачи - типа создать "nested" форму с кучей форм эреев внутри и так далее - делают максимальную декомпозицию

Comment: в вашем случае как раз речь идет о [dumb components](https://angular-checklist.io/default/checklist/architecture/Z1eHhoR)

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Композиция или декомпозиция - вопрос философский, а если отвечать на поставленный вопрос, то причина в том, что у вас по сути 1 форма отрисованная N раз, т.к. вы используете одну и туже `FormGroup` переменную `form`. Просто сделайте `form` массивом `FormGroup[]` и не понадобится никакая магия.